# TSLint complaining that 'Express bodyParser is deprecated'

Tags: typescript, express, tslint

Hoe to get rid of the warning `bodyParser is deprecated. (deprecation)tslint(1)` I don't really want to disable next line, is there a better way?

This is my index.ts

```
import { app } from './app';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const hostname = process.env.HOST;
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

and this is app.ts

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { routes } from './routes';
export const app: Application = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // bodyParser is deprecated. (deprecation)tslint(1)
routes(app);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BodyParser is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525078/bodyparser-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use the built-in body parser lib from `express` itself excepted if you have REALLY good reason to use `body-parser` which is deprecated since 2019.

instead of doing :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

simply do

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Also on a sidenote, `tslint` is also deprecated. Now, you should use `eslint` even when using typescript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this tslint rule by setting the `"deprecation"` key to `false` in your tslint.json file

Example tslint.json file:

```json
{
  "deprecation": false
}
```

Do however notice that this will disable every single deprecation notice. If you want to only disable the deprecation notice for the next line you can use a comment flag with rule names.

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:deprecation
app.use(bodyParser.json());
routes(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use body-parser anymore

If you are using Express 4.16+ the body parsing functionality has come with express as builtin

You use

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

from directly express

so you can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`, and simply go with the express method.